# Possible to add tabs before the new line generated by Textbox with WrapWithOverFlow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, string, visual-studio-2010

In my xaml code I'm using a textbox inside my Expander which I have set it's

```
TestWrapping = "WrapWithOveFlow
```

Hence, whenever the line is too long, textbox automatically breaks the to a new line.
However, since this list gets really squished I want to implement kind of indentation to add to it's readability.

I am wondering is there any way to set the textbox to add a tab (\t) to the start of the new line which it broke from a longer line then instead of

```
TITLE: this is a test text and it's
very long
TITLE: this is another test line which
is also very long.
```

I end up with

```
TITLE: this is a test text and it's
       very long
TITLE: this is another test line which
       is also very long.
```

I know there are so many methods to do this, and I am open to hear them. However I am curious to know the answer for this question as well as it will be very simple and easy to do.

**Added Info**
I am filling up this textbox using

```
Text = {Binding testBindingVar}
```

which the value of *testBindingVar* gets filled up using

```
testBindingVar += "TITLE: added stuff long and short"
```

by the GUI and the user interaction. and I like it's simplicity which doesn't require dealing with Grids and tables.